# trying to change screen when clicking on text but Unexpected toke expecting ";" Error instead

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, frontend, onpress

Hey I've been testing different ways to try and navigate to another page by clicking on an image, so I've been testing on a mock-up (this code) to be able to navigate to "AddDocScreen" by clicking on a text but it gives me an error instead. Can anyone help please

here is the error:

```
Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(SyntaxError: /Users/camillebasbous/Project/App.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (30:27)

[0m [90m 28 | [39m[0m
[0m [90m 29 | [39m        [0m
[0m[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 30 | [39m       navigateToScreen () [33m=>[39m () [33m=>[39m {[0m
[0m [90m    | [39m                           [31m[1m^[22m[39m[0m
[0m [90m 31 | [39m [0m
[0m [90m 32 | [39m        [36mconst[39m navigationAction [33m=[39m [33mNavigationActions[39m[33m.[39mnavigate({[0m
[0m [90m 33 | [39m           routeName[33m:[39m [32m'AddDocSreen'[39m[33m,[39m[0m (null))

__38-[RCTCxxBridge loadSource:onProgress:]_block_invoke.228
    RCTCxxBridge.mm:414
___ZL36attemptAsynchronousLoadOfBundleAtURLP5NSURLU13block_pointerFvP18RCTLoadingProgressEU13block_pointerFvP7NSErrorP9RCTSourceE_block_invoke.118
__80-[RCTMultipartDataTask URLSession:streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:]_block_invoke
-[RCTMultipartStreamReader emitChunk:headers:callback:done:]
-[RCTMultipartStreamReader readAllPartsWithCompletionCallback:progressCallback:]
-[RCTMultipartDataTask URLSession:streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:]
__88-[NSURLSession delegate_streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:completionHandler:]_block_invoke
__NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
-[NSBlockOperation main]
-[__NSOperationInternal _start:]
__NSOQSchedule_f
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_continuation_pop
_dispatch_async_redirect_invoke
_dispatch_root_queue_drain
_dispatch_worker_thread2
_pthread_wqthread
start_wqthread
```

Here is the Mockup code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, Text} from "react-native" ;
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, StackActions, NavigationActions, navigateToScreen } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json
import AddDocScreen from './Menu/AddDocScreen'





export default class Mock extends React.Component{
    render(){


        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>

           <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={ this.navigateToScreen('AddDocScreen') }>
        <View><Text>Click Me</Text></View>
</TouchableOpacity>


            </View>
        )
    }
}


       navigateToScreen () => () => {

        const navigationAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
           routeName: 'AddDocSreen',


})
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigationAction)
    }





const doc = createStackNavigator({
  AddDocScreen: {screen: AddDocScreen},
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(215,215,215,1)',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed a semicolon:

```js
import AddDocScreen from './Menu/AddDocScreen'
```

Also, make sure you add a semicolon to your `return` statements as well. For future reference, the error itself tells you where the problem is with syntax errors.

```js
Unexpected token, expected ";" (30:27)
```

That means you missed a semicolon on line 30, character 27. Without being able to look at your line numbers, I can't tell you for sure that's the (only) spot, but just look at line endings to see where a semicolon is missing.

Edit:
Also, looking at your code again, found another error:

```js
onPress={ this.navigateToScreen('AddDocScreen') }>
```

Should be

```js
onPress={ () => this.navigateToScreen('AddDocScreen') }>
```

Edit edit: (I really hate not being able to add comments)
You mentioned `navigateToScreen () => () => {` being the error. That makes sense.
I apologize for missing it before! In React Native, you want the method signature to look like

```js
navigateToScreen() {
 ... code ...
}
```

The way you're currently doing it is almost ES6 (That would be `function = () => {};`), but not React Native. You can see an example on [this tutorial page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches). Note how the method looks like

```js
  _onPressButton() {
    Alert.alert('You tapped the button!')
  }
```